# No .bash_profile on my Mac

Tags: eclipse, bash, macos, terminal

I'm trying to develop using Eclipse/Maven on my Mac and while setting environment variables there is no .bash_profile. I do ls -a and still not there. I see a .bash_history and .bash_sessions. Where am I supposed to set my JAVA_HOME and PATH?

Thank you!

Comment: Just create the file. You might also be interested in this: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In your terminal:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

Then make your edits and save. This is generic so make sure your path is correct in the above example.

Comment: This won't work on Mac 10.12. File needs to be created if Sierra is a fresh install. Use `nano ~/.bash_profile` to create it in the home directory.

Comment: You can also do vim .bash_profile or just vim .profile to create new file in terminal.

Comment: Works in mojave. Thank you.

Comment: touch ~/.bash_profile works in Ventura 13.2 on an M2. I then used vi to edit it.

Answer (score 25):

For anyone else stumbling up on this after Mac Catalina,

Starting CATALINA the default shell is zsh.
The profile file name for zsh is ~/.zprofile.

To setup bash as your default:

1. Open terminal
2. Goto preferences and choose "Shell opens with"
3. Click on "Command(complete path)" and type "/bin/bash" to start bash shell

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried a dozen of things on my mac with Big Sur but it didn't work. Creating .profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc didn't help because I was not running bash but zsh‍♂️.

Answer (score 0):

On terminal, enter this command: `chsh -s /bin/bash`

This will change shell for the current user to bash.

After that, you can see .bash_profile on the root folder.